# Android :: How To Read Not Visible Child Elements Of List View?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-listview

I have a list view which contains some 20 odd items from database along with a two Buttons and an extra TextView as a counter enclosed within linear layout. The two buttons usually for increment and decrement the value in an extra TextView. What i want is when i  press button outside the listView should fetch all items along with an value of an extra text. Right now I can fetch Linear layouts and there child items which are visible on screen i.e. out 20 items 10 are visible on screen, so my question is how to fetch the remaining items along with extra Textview values enclosed within linear layout which are not visible which can be viewed when we scroll the Listview?

Here is main.xml file

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation= "horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CBCBCB">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget64"
android:background="@drawable/toolbar_color"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="0px"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dip">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/save_creature_for_encounter"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/onclick_button_bg" 
    android:layout_width="40dip" android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:text="Save"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/back_show_encounter"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_color"
    android:layout_height="50dip">
    </Button>
  </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
               android:layout_gravity="center"    
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:layout_marginTop="28dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>  
      </FrameLayout>
```

And here is my custom_list.xml file

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="test" android:id="@+id/item_creatures_to_encounter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_width="180dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="30px"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget66"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="myDescClickHandler">
                >
                </Button>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/asc"
                android:layout_width="30px"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="10dip"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/widget66"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="myAscClickHandler">

                >
                </Button>

                <TextView android:text="@string/counter" android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_width="30dip"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Here is my custom Adapter file

```
   public class DomainAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public DomainAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Cursor data) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        //final ViewHolder holder;
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            holder.add = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.asc);
            Button.OnClickListener b = 
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
                    TextView label=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    Log.d("AAAAJJJAAA", ""+ parent);
                    CharSequence value = ((TextView) label).getText();
                    int count = Integer.parseInt((String) value);
                     count++;
                     String inc = String.format("%d", count);
                    label.setText(inc);
                    //parent.refreshDrawableState();       
                }
            };
            holder.add.setOnClickListener(b);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

}

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand anything. Can you post some layout files? Do you know what is ViewHolder pattern and the view recycling?

Comment: @GagleKas i have attached the xml files as per your request. I dont how ViewHolder pattern goes as i am newbie in Android.

Comment: I have edited my post and included the Image of emulator for a clear picture so on pressing save button on top right corner i want to collect all items in list and values of textView which at present is 0 in all lists on right hand side which can be increment or decrement two the two buttons marked + and - on listView itself.

Comment: Actually i found to find child elements of listview final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
Adapter adapter = lv.getAdapter();
          Log.d("ADPATOR", ""+ adapter.getCount());
             for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){            
              LinearLayout eView = (LinearLayout)  lv.getChildAt(i);
              int total = lv.getChildCount();
              Log.d("VIEW TOTAL", ""+ total + " List count "+ eView);
             }   but still can't find the item which are not visible , i am almost there just some help from somebody

Comment: So, when you click on save button you want to get the values from the textviews (the textview at the right of + and - buttons)?

Answer (score 2):

The Views that are outside the visible area does not exists. ListView creates only the amount of views that are on the screen.

When you scroll, and a View disappears it reuses that View. It actually asks for the Adapter to modify the parameters of the View and it uses the modified View.

Example:

Let view1 be your first row (the one that's text is avatar). When you scroll down, "avatar" disappears and a new one becomes visible at the bottom. The ListView doesn't need view1 anymore, because it is not visible. So it gives view1 to the Adapter and asks it to modify view1's parameters to be the new row. The adapter sets the text on view1 to the next row (eg. "human") and returns it to the ListView. The ListView will display the view1 at the bottom of the list.

So basically the views that are outside the visible area doesn't exists.

What you can do: save the count to the adapter when a user presses the + or - buttons.

Then you can ask for the data items (`listView.getItemAtPosition(int position)`) and count those.

Code sample for this:

```
class DataForView {
    int counter;
}

ListView mListView;
...

int sumCounter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<mListView.getCount(); i++) {
  sumCounter += ((DataForView)mListView.getItem(i)).counter;
}
```

Look at the following tutorial for custom Adapters:

http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: I have edited my post and included the Image of emulator for a clear picture so on pressing save button on top right corner i want to collect all items in list and values of textView which at present is 0 in all lists on right hand side which can be increment or decrement two the two buttons marked + and - on listView itself.

Comment: I understood the question the first time. I can provide you a code example if you post how you created the ListView and how you set up the +, - buttons. I'm not sure that the +,- buttons are actually working in your implementation (try to increase the first row, and scroll down, at the bottom of the list, increase another row, and scroll up. Are your changes preserved?)

Comment: @bbalazs yes you r right its not preserving the changes when i try to increase the any row and when i scroll it shift the value to next row.

Comment: Yes, that's because what I said to you: you can't do it this way. You have to create a custom Adapter and the +, - buttons have to modify the data in your Adapter, and not your View. Please read the tutorial pdf that I've posted, especially the "Interactive Rows" section - there is just what you need.

Comment: @bbalazs i have edited my post and included my java file and i have created custom Adapter named DomainAdapter , So please guide me how i should modify +,- buttons in the Adaptor and rest of my needs in the post.

Comment: I'll send a detailed example in the evening, when I get home from work. In the meantime: some quick guidelines: try first with a custom ArrayAdapter (easier to understand); try to override the adapter's getView method; create a simple data class (eg. MyData with a String text and an int counter) and try MyArrayAdapter<MyData>; override the toString() method of MyData.

Comment: Man, what you are asking is really complex to explain here because it envolves some concepts: ListActivity, adapter with ViewHolder pattern implementation and array of data (in your case array of Creatures with name and value). I could post here the solution you are asking with a custom HolderAdapter I've made, but as I said it's very long to post here. You should first understand the concepts and if you have any question post it here. It's like "Explain me Java JDBC programming."

Comment: @bbalazs @GagleKas i have created custom adpater i have edited my post and added that but onclick + button not doing any thing, please guide.

Comment: @GagleKas can you mail me on my emailid prakashsejwani@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

1. List view doesn't contain ALL the children. When you scroll it, it creates only visible items on run time. 
   2. If you want to get all the children altogether, Better keep an ArrayList of the child objects that your list has. You can add or remove children to this ArrayList as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

get the ListView's adapter instance and then try calling getItem ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29)

Comment: getItem just gives the value of database item from the ListView's adapter, so how i will get the value of extra TextView in ListView?